# jquery reenable prevent default after prevent default

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an input type submit button. I am calling the bootstrap dialog box as follow but it is not functioning as expected. It will not reenable the preventdefault to go to the httppost action as specific by the form

**What am I intend to do?** 
When user click on the button, it will not trigger form submission but instead trigger the bootstrap dialog box. If user confirm the dialog box, it will redirect to httppost form submission to delete the item. If user cancel the confirmation, it will remain in same page.

**What am I avoiding to do in this case**? 
retrigger the form submission httppost url using ajax call or any other method in the confirmation. I do not want to use $.ajax to trigger form submission again.

```
$('.classname').on('click touchstart', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      BootstrapDialog.confirm('Hi Apple, are you sure?', function(result) {
           if(result) {
               alert('Yup.');
               $('.classname').unbind('click touchstart');
           } else {
               alert('Nope.');
           }
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could submit the FORM manually:

```
$('.classname').on('click touchstart', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      BootstrapDialog.confirm('Hi Apple, are you sure?', function(result) {
           if(result) {
               alert('Yup.');
               //submit the FORM
               $(this).closest('form').submit(); // or whatever to target specific FORM
               // you could have to call the native submit method instead
               // then use: $(this).closest('form')[0].submit();
               // an other solution could be:
               // $(this).off('click touchstart').click();
           } else {
               alert('Nope.');
           }
      });
 });
```

Comment: i follow the second method $('.classname').off('click touchstart').click() but i receive concurrency exception for deleting data from database